# Combine 2 metrics for an overall “score”?

Tags: data-transformation

I have 2 metrics, screen size and screen resolution. These are independent of one another but do probably correlate. I’m looking for a way of combining them into an overall “score” to use against other variables but i’m unsure of the best way to do it!

Edit: I think I can just multiply the numbers together?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you value? // Economics often talks about combining multiple sources of value into one *utility function*. You might want to read about such a concept.